# SonarQube complains: Either log or rethrow this exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, sonarqube

I am running SonarQube 5 for code quality check after integrating the code with Maven.

Sonar is complaining that I should:

> Either log or rethrow this exception.

in following piece of code:

```java
public static Date convertStringtoDate(String stringDate) {
    stringDate = StringUtils.trimToNull(stringDate);
    SimpleDateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date date = null;

    if (stringDate != null) {
        try {
            date = dfm.parse(stringDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Cannot convert String to Date: ",convertStringtoDate(e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    return date;    
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it going recursion ?? Try removing convertStringtoDate() method call from your logger and keep only string staement

Comment: In case you wanted to ignore this warning on purpose (e.g. an exception is part of your business logic), you can use the following annotation:

@SuppressWarnings("squid:S1166") // The exception is part of the process and is avoided on purpose to prevent flooding logs.

On a side note, I'm surprised that Sonar does not complain about catching Exception instead of one of its implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, is this behaviour correct? Seems a bit weird that you are trying to call `convertStringtoDate` on the exception message as well.

Secondly, I had the same problem with Sonar recently. Seems like you need to pass the whole exception as a parameter to the logger, instead of `e.getMessage()` for Sonar to realize you are logging the exception.

Try this instead:

```
public static Date convertStringtoDate(String stringDate){
    stringDate = StringUtils.trimToNull(stringDate);
    SimpleDateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    if(stringDate!=null){
        try {
            date = dfm.parse(stringDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Cannot convert String to Date: ", e);
        }
    }
    return date;    
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Part of the point of this rule is rule is to not loose the _context_ of the exception, which you do when you only log the message.