# Either log this exception and handle it, or rethrow it with some contextual information

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarlint

Can some one help me why SonarLint is showing this:

> Either log this exception and handle it, or rethrow it with some contextual information.

for below piece of code.

```
public static <T> T getObjectFromJson(final Object jsonString, final Class<T> valueType) {
        T object = null;
        if (jsonString != null) {
            try {
                object = MAPPER.readValue(jsonString.toString(), valueType);
            } catch (IOException io) {
                log.error(ERROR_LOG_STR + " in method getObjectFromJson(). Exception Message={}, Exception Stack ={}",
                        io.getMessage(), io);
                throw new ServiceException(ErrorMessages.JSON_SERIALIZATION_ERROR, io.getCause());
            }
        }
        return object;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sonar complaining about logging and rethrowing the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122271/sonar-complaining-about-logging-and-rethrowing-the-exception)

Comment: No my catch block diff compare to above solution

Comment: @eol Probably we should ask for the __RSPEC id__ shown when clicking on _Rule_ details. I suppose [RSPEC-1166](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-1166) ( answered by your marked duplicate) is __not the only__ non-compliant issue here: also and foremost [RSPEC-2139](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/error-handling/RSPEC-2139), see my answer ️

Answer (score 6):

It's about the **either** ... **or**, see Sonar's [Rule spec RSPEC-2139](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/error-handling/RSPEC-2139):

> Exceptions should be either logged or rethrown **but not both**

To be compliant with the rule, decide for one:

1. either log only:

```java
            try {
                object = MAPPER.readValue(jsonString.toString(), valueType);
            } catch (IOException io) {
                log.error(ERROR_LOG_STR + " in method getObjectFromJson(). Exception Message={}, Exception Stack ={}",
                        io.getMessage(), io);
            }
```

2. or throw only:

```java
           try {
               object = MAPPER.readValue(jsonString.toString(), valueType);
           } catch (IOException io) {
               throw new ServiceException(ErrorMessages.JSON_SERIALIZATION_ERROR, io);  // would use the full exception, not only the wrapped .getCause()
           }
```

#### Bonus: How to achieve both and simplify

You can log additionally in a global or local error-handling interceptor like Spring's `@ControllerAdvice` annotated error-handler.

Most loggers allow to pass a `Throwable` when logging at error-level.
For example using [Slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html#error(java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)): `log.error(ERROR_LOG_STR + " in method getObjectFromJson(): " + io.getMessage(), io)`

See also:

- [How to log exception and message with placeholders with SLF4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951209/how-to-log-exception-and-message-with-placeholders-with-slf4j)
- Baeldung tutorial: [Logging Exceptions Using SLF4J](https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-log-exceptions)

#### Related Rules

[RSPEC-1166](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/error-handling/RSPEC-1166): Exception handlers should preserve the original exceptions

The [spec feature](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-1166) was resolved 2018-11-02 with version 5.9, [implementation for Java](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-3029) fixed 2019-02-15 with version 5.11.

**⚠️ Partial fix only**:
The [marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70608131/either-log-this-exception-and-handle-it-or-rethrow-it-with-some-contextual-info/70608728#comment124817603_70608131)
and [obourgain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70608346/5730279) do not solve the two-fold case here completely:

1. they fix RSPEC-1166
2. but not RSPEC-2139

Similar questions coping with RSPEC-1166:

- [SONAR complaining about logging and rethrowing an Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411450/sonar-complaining-about-logging-and-rethrowing-an-exception), asked 2016
- [Either log or rethrow this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197329/either-log-or-rethrow-this-exception), asked 2015
- [Sonar complaining about logging and rethrowing the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122271/sonar-complaining-about-logging-and-rethrowing-the-exception), asked 2015